# How to create a Power point Template using powerpoint javascript API's?

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I was very new to this. I'm trying to automate a slide creation part which we used mostly and I'm using office 365 package. Right now I was trying to automate this process. When a user clicks a button I just want to insert a sample template for them which has Header and Footer and body. I refer the below links for that too. But I'm not able to find any useful resources.

[Power Point Office Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins)

```
 Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
    "Hello World!",
    {
      coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text
    },
    result => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.error(result.error.message);
      }
    }
  );
```

While I was clicking the button I Can able to insert `Hello World!` but I can't able to insert some HTML content with the help of this API (I tried `Office.CoercionType.Html` and figure out it'll only work word and outlook add-on). And also any Idea of how to insert charts also?

Comment: Unfortunately, Word and Excel have far more Office.js resources than PowerPoint. This ebook _Building Office Add-ins using Office.js_ is well worth the price: https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins

Comment: Ok, will try it. But if there are any free resources please comment it here...